# Data fetched from sqlite not showing in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, firebase

```
    messageList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_list);
    mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

    messageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(messages);
    messageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

final MainData mHelper = new MainData(this);
    final Cursor csr = mHelper.getAllQuestions3();
            sqlite = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
            valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

//I add the data from firebase to SQLITE here 


                while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                    String mSender = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SENDER));
                    String mMessage = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE));
                    long mTime = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME));
                    String mSeen = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SEEN));
                    String mTimer = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMER));
                    String mType = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));

                    messages.add(new SQLiteHelper(mSender, mMessage, mType, mSeen, mTimer, mTime));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                    mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).setValue(null);

        }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
            sqlite.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Adapter

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder>{
ChatData mHelper;
Cursor csr;
private List<SQLiteHelper> mMessagesHelperList;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


public MessagesAdapter(List<SQLiteHelper> MessagesHelperList) {
    this.mMessagesHelperList = MessagesHelperList;
}


public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView messageText;


    public MessageViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());


        mHelper = new ChatData(view.getContext(),"MessagePlus",null,1);
        csr = mHelper.getAllQuestions3();

        messageText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
    }
}

@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_activity_chat,parent,false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    return new MessageViewHolder(V);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SQLiteHelper messagesHelper = mMessagesHelperList.get(position);

       holder.messageText.setText(messagesHelper.getMessage());
    }

@Override
public  int getItemCount() {
    return mMessagesHelperList.size();
}
```

I have another activity where i fetch sqlite data and show it in recyclerview and it works and i had achieved that the same way as this. Here too it used to work but then i added some features and moved around some code and now its not working and i have checked the whole code numerous times but still not finding why its not working...

**The table and rows exists with data and the size of list too isnt null**

Just discovered that the Adapter isnt getting called when i added Logs inside it. Thats where the problem is but idk why

Comment: how many times `onBindViewHolder` is called? tried to add some `Log.d` inside?

Comment: Oh wait... not even once... wtf why is that??? @pskink

Comment: inside `getItemCount()` try to `Log.d` the value of `mMessagesHelperList.size()` - what do you see?

Comment: not showing anything... but in activity i tried arraylist.size and it showed 3 @pskink

Comment: messages.size shows 3... but in adapter if i put a log it dsnt show anything

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adding the extra messages to the list that you first created your adapter so

instead of

```
messages.add(new SQLiteHelper(mSender, mMessage, mType, mSeen, mTimer, mTime));
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

do

```
mAdapter.add(new SQLiteHelper(mSender, mMessage, mType, mSeen, mTimer, mTime));
```

and in your adapter you have to add the add function like that

```
public void add(SQLiteHelper item){
    if(mMessagesHelperList!=null){
        mMessagesHelperList.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

also

you have too much "trash" on your code, on your ValueEventListener you are trying to read the values of a cursor and not the ds (DataSnapshot). so probably your cursor there is empty. If the cursor is empty you don't add any item to the adapter, so the adapter don't have items to show, so onBindViewHolder correctly don't get called

Comment: Still no luck... I just added a log inside onBindViewer to see how many times its calling and i didnt get a result which means its not callig onbindviewer at all... problem over there i guesss

Comment: are you sure that the ValueEventListener gets called? put a breakpoint on that function

Comment: The value event listener gets called for sure... i have a log,d at it shows so yeah its getting called

Comment: you have too much "trash" on your code, on your `ValueEventListener ` you are trying to read the values of a cursor and not the ds (DataSnapshot). so probably your cursor there is empty. If the cursor is empty you don't add any item to the adapter, so the adapter don't have items to show, so onBindViewHolder correctly don't get called

Comment: curson isnt empty and i need to put it in valueventlistener because i fetch data from firebase to add it there